# How to find the architecture of OS installed

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, computer-architecture

I'm using Core 2 Duo. From Intel website I found that it is a 64-bit architecture CPU.

Long back I've installed Ubuntu OS on this machine. But I'm not sure if I installed the x86-32 or x86-64 version of Linux. I want to know which version of Linux I'm using. How can I get to know that?

How do I find the same on Windows?

Comment: Please note that you probably won't find terms x86-32 or x86-64 mentioned if GNU/Linux utilities. Most likely you'll see something like i386/i486/i586/i686 for 32bit CPUs and amd64 for 64bit CPUs (original Intel 64bit CPUs were not part of the x86 family, so  64 bit extensions to x86 instruction set are often called amd64 because AMD made first x86 64bit processors).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Unix-like OSes you can type `uname -m` to show the architecture:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Under Windows follow Microsoft's [guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions):

> To find out if your computer is running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, do the following:

```
    Open System by clicking the Start button, right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.

    Under System, you can view the system type.

If your computer is running Windows XP, do the following:

    Click Start.

    Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.

        If you don't see "x64 Edition" listed, then you're running the 32-bit version of Windows XP.

        If "x64 Edition" is listed under System, you're running the 64-bit version of Windows XP.
```

Answer (score 18):

On Windows Vista and newer you can run the command

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

to find out whether it's 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 10):

From the console run

```
set
```

and look for the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE value`. In my case:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
```

Or just print from the beggining

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

Answer (score 6):

Complementing [Tofystedeth's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/173788/how-to-find-the-architecture-of-os-installed/173808#173808), in Windows XP (and newer) you can use `cpu`'s AddressWidth and DataWidth to get the data you need.

If you want to find the architecture of the OS:

```
wmic cpu get AddressWidth
```

If you want to find the architecture of the processor itself:

```
wmic cpu get DataWidth
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows XP will report 32-bit regardless of the processor architecture when running the "wmic cpu get DataWidth" command.

Comment: If anyone's getting `wmic installing...` and then you get an error, what worked for me right after is, I type in the same cmd window: `wmic` got console: `wmic:root\cli>` and typed `cpu get AddressWidth` or `cpu get DataWidth`...both gave `32` (!!no need to precede with `wmic`)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, check out this document from Microsoft. It tells you how to find out for any version of Windows you might have:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218[link text](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218)

For Windows 7, check the instructions here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: This document is only for Windows XP & WIndows Server 2003 versions.

Comment: ...except for all the Parts where it says "Vista".

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10... *Settings* → *System* and then *About* (bottom left corner). It should be listed under *Device Specifications*: *64 bit operating system and x64-based processor*.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about Windows 10, it asked how to tell which version of **Linux** (64-bit or 32-bit) is installed.

Comment: @Blackwood, "How to find the same on windows?".  Other answers cover earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: @fixer1234 That will tell you whether the installed version of Windows is 64-bit or 32-bit, and whether it is running on a 64-bit or 32-bit CPU. It won't tell you if you have installed a 32-bit version of Linux on your 64-bit computer. The question asks *I want to know which version of Linux I'm using*

Comment: @Blackwood, you're referring to the first question.  The next sentence in the question is the second question that this answer refers to.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux,

```
uname -a
```

shows information about the current running kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You may run msinfo32.exe (window *System Information*) on your system (in a command prompt). Check *System Type* under *System Summary*.

Comment: On Windows 10 there does not appear to be a *"System Type"*.